# PHP in Wordpress?

Tags: php

I'm stuck with a question. How far can I go with php with wordpress? If good it's of course not the same as using a server+db and a .php file to script everything you can imagine, but how far can I go with Wordpress?

For example you have your standard while's etc. but then you have inserting, what if I want to insert something like this in a field in wordpress? Would this even be possible or something related to things like `substr`?

```
    $firstletter = $row['Name'];
    $firstletter2 = substr($firstletter, 0,1);

    $return .= '<li data letter="'.$firstletter2.'" >';
     }
   return friendly ($firstletter2);
```

Comment: The entire back end of WordPress is written in php. it's not just a templating language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use everything that is available in PHP, as WordPress is a script depending on PHP.

The only limitations you have are set by your version of PHP, and if you run huge scripts, your server configuration.

Comment: Is it maybe possible for you to give me an example or link me anything exampling how to insert data into a custom field/field using wordpress? The simplest thing I can come up with(usual php) is `INSERT into ... WHERE ...`, I just have no idea how to do this in a Wordpress way. I have a little bit of experience with Wordpress but not to much.

Comment: You can use the [$wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)-Class for that.